# Processing large raster file in R - lots of RAM, very slow read/write

Tags: r, raster, spatial

I have a very large raster file (dimensions are (nrow, ncol, ncell) = (96523, 153811, 14846299153) and I am trying to apply some functions to it. Firstly, reclassify().

Doing this how I might for a small file, e.g.  `reclassify(r,rcl=m,filename = fname,NAflag = 0,  overwrite = FALSE, progress = "text", options = c("COMPRESS=Deflate","PREDICTOR=1","ZLEVEL=6")) )` just takes far too long on my machine (it hasn't finished in 10 hours, and I have many such rasters to work through).

To get a sense of how long it would take I coarsened the raster (nrow(r) = nrow(r)/8, or /4... and same for ncol(r)). When dividing by 8 it ran on my computer in 30 seconds. When dicigind by 4 in about 2 mins. When dividing by 2, it didn't finish in 6 hours. I have no idea why it didn't scale as expected. Any insight on this would be helpful??

I tried to use clusterR(..reclassify..) to use more cores and speed this up, but I never did seem to manage to actually speed things up, no matter how many cores I set.

So now I am trying to use a server that has many cores and a lot more RAM to make this faster. But the server is very very slow at read/write operations. So the usual procedure of holding the raster on disk and reading in a tiny sliver, processing it, and writing that sliver takes far too long. Indeed the nrow/8 version that ran on my system in 30 seconds takes hours on this server.

I tried to read the whole raster into RAM. There should be enough avaialble (about 2TB is available) but it keeps crashing around 600GB.

Now I am trying to figure out how to increase the chunksize so that the server can read more, but not all, of the raster into memory each time so there are not too many read/write operations. But I am not sure how.

Anyway sorry for the text wall. Any advice would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

## 1. Scaling the problem down

You describe scaling the problem down as follows:

> To get a sense of how long it would take I coarsened the raster (nrow(r) = nrow(r)/8, or /4... and same for ncol(r)). When dividing by 8 it ran on my computer in 30 seconds. When dividing by 4 in about 2 mins. When dividing by 2, it didn't finish in 6 hours. I have no idea why it didn't scale as expected. Any insight on this would be helpful??

One might expect that if you take 1/8 the number rows and 1/8 the number of columns, there would be 1/64 the number of cells; similarly, taking 1/2 rows and 1/2 columns would bring it down to 1/4 as many cells. However, the time required to complete the entire task is not likely to be strictly proportional to the number of cells, due to bottlenecks, such as disk read/write operations or allocating memory for data structures.

## 2. Insufficient memory

> I tried to read the whole raster into RAM. There should be enough available (about 2TB is available) but it keeps crashing around 600GB.

It is a common misperception that an object [of moderate size] will fit in [a large amount of] memory. For many reasons, it often does not work out that way.

## 3. Chunk size

> Now I am trying to figure out how to increase the chunksize so that the server can read more, but not all, of the raster into memory each time so there are not too many read/write operations. But I am not sure how.

You are on the right track in seeking a happy balance between chunk size and number of read/write cycles. The `raster` package has two functions that can help in this area:

1. `raster::canProcessInMemory()` tells whether the amount of memory needed for the function is available, and,
2. `raster::blockSize()` suggests the number of rows to use for each chunk, along with the corresponding row numbers.

### Raster algebra

As described in https://rspatial.org/raster/pkg/4-algebra.html#raster-algebra, many generic functions that allow for simple and elegant raster algebra have been implemented for Raster* objects, including the normal algebraic operators such as { +, -, *, / }, logical operators such as { >, >=, <, ==, ! } and functions such as { abs, round, ceiling, floor, trunc, sqrt, log, log10, exp, cos, sin, max, min, range, prod, sum, any, all }. In these functions you can mix raster objects with numbers, as long as the first argument is a raster object.

### Writing functions for large rasters

Appendix I at https://rspatial.org/raster/pkg/appendix1.html#appendix-i-writing-functions-for-large-raster-files describes how to write functions for large raster files. In particular, example function `f8()` describes a function that will accept a large raster and apply whatever function we choose to that raster one block at a time. Something like this:

```
block_fun <- function( big_raster, do_what ){
   for( i in 1:num_blocks ){
      get_block_data( i )       # from    big_raster
      process_block_data( i )   # using    do_what
      save_chunk( i )
   }
```

Then we can compose functions using the raster algebra described above, for example:

```
f1 <- function( x ) sqrt( x )
f2 <- function( x ) x + 3
f3 <- function( x ) sin( x / 180 )
```

### Demonstration

```
# Get a raster file for demonstration
require( rgdal )     # for loading a raster from a file
large_raster <- raster::raster( 'path/to/a/large/raster/file.tif' )
```

```
# Define the block-by-block function

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Adapted from
#   https://rspatial.org/raster/pkg/appendix1.html#a-complete-function
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------

process_large_raster <- function(
    input_raster
  , f = function( r ) sin( r / 180 )
  , chunk_file_name = ''
  , overwrite = FALSE )
  , ...
){

  chunk            <- raster::raster( input_raster )
  chunk_file_name  <- raster::trim( chunk_file_name )
  
  # Find out if the amount of memory needed for the function is available
  # n : integer number of copies of the Raster* object cell values
  #     this function needs to be able to have in memory

  RASTER_FITS_IN_MEMORY <- raster::canProcessInMemory(
    x = chunk, n = 3, verbose = TRUE
  )
  
  # ---------------------------------------------------------
  # Can we process this whole raster in memory all at once?
  # If not, use a temporary raster file to process chunks
  #    writeStart [ writeValues ... ] writeStop
  #     Open      [ save parts ...  ]  Close
  # ---------------------------------------------------------
  
  # Use memory to process the raster, unless either of the following is true
  #  *  The raster is too large to process in memory
  #  *  A file name is given
  
  # Create a temporary file if the raster is too large to fit in memory
  if( !RASTER_FITS_IN_MEMORY & chunk_file_name == '' ){
    chunk_file_name <- raster::rasterTmpFile()
  }
  
  if( chunk_file_name != '' ){   # File name is available
    # Use a RASTER
    chunk <- raster::writeStart( chunk, chunk_file_name, ... )
    write_chunks_to_file <- TRUE
  } else {                       # File name is NOT available
    # Use a MATRIX
    matrix_chunk <- matrix( ncol = nrow( chunk ), nrow = ncol( chunk ))
    write_chunks_to_file <- FALSE
  }
  
  # Obtain suggested chunk sizes (number of rows and corresponding row numbers)
  block <- raster::blockSize( input_raster )
  
  progress_bar <- raster::pbCreate( block$n, ... )

  chunk_to_file <- function(){
    raster::writeValues( chunk, v, block$row[ i ] )
  }

  chunk_to_memory <- function(){
    cols <- block$row[ i ]:( block$row[ i ] + block$nrows[ i ] - 1 )
    matrix_chunk[ , cols ] <- matrix( v, nrow = chunk@ncols )
    matrix_chunk
  }
  
  save_chunk <- function(){
    if( write_chunks_to_file ){     # to file
      chunk_to_file()
    } else {                        # to memory
      chunk_to_memory()
    }
    raster::pbStep( progress_bar, i )
  }

  save_result <- function( blocks_remaining ){
    if( write_chunks_to_file ){
      chunk <- raster::writeStop( chunk )
    } else { if( blocks_remaining ){
      chunk <- raster::setValues( chunk, as.vector( matrix_chunk ))
    }}
    chunk
  }

  get_block_data <- function(){
    raster::getValues( input_raster, row = block$row[ i ], nrows = block$nrows[ i ] )
  }

  process_block_data <- function( v ){
    f( v )
  }

  close_chunk_file <- function( a_chunked_raster ){
    raster::writeStop( a_chunked_raster )  
  }

  mat2ras <- function( mtrx, rstr ){
    # Given a matrix and a raster, set the values of the raster
    # using values from the matrix
    # Return the raster with updated values
    raster::setValues( rstr, as.vector( mtrx ))      
  }

  and_finally <- function(){
    raster::pbClose( progress_bar )
    if( write_chunks_to_file ){
      close_chunk_file( a_chunked_raster = chunk )
    } else {
      mat2ras( mtrx = as.numeric( matrix_chunk ), rstr = chunk )
    } 
  }

  # ============================================
    for( i in 1:block$n ){
      v <- get_block_data()
      v <- process_block_data( v )
      save_chunk()
     
      if( write_chunks_to_file ){
        chunk <- chunk_to_file()
      } else {
        matrix_chunk <- chunk_to_memory()
      }
    }    
  # ============================================

  and_finally()
}
```

### Calling our new function

```
process_large_raster( input_raster = large_raster, f = f1)

#             GB
# available : 3.54
#       60% : 2.12
#    needed : 0.05
#   allowed : 4.66  (if available)

# class      : RasterLayer 
# dimensions : 1230, 1877, 2308710  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution : 0.0002695, 0.0002695  (x, y)
# extent     : -121.9, -121.4, 37.85, 38.19  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
# source     : memory
# names      : layer 
# values     : 0.2824, 0.5955  (min, max)

process_large_raster( input_raster = large_raster, f = f2)

#             GB
# available : 3.53
#       60% : 2.12
#    needed : 0.05
#   allowed : 4.66  (if available)

# class      : RasterLayer 
# dimensions : 1230, 1877, 2308710  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution : 0.0002695, 0.0002695  (x, y)
# extent     : -121.9, -121.4, 37.85, 38.19  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
# source     : memory
# names      : layer 
# values     : 3.08, 3.355  (min, max)

process_large_raster( input_raster = large_raster, f = f3 )

#             GB
# available : 2.97
#       60% : 1.78
#    needed : 0.05
#   allowed : 4.66  (if available)

# class      : RasterLayer 
# dimensions : 1230, 1877, 2308710  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution : 0.0002695, 0.0002695  (x, y)
# extent     : -121.9, -121.4, 37.85, 38.19  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
# source     : memory
# names      : layer 
# values     : 0.000443, 0.00197  (min, max)
```

So far, so good. But things about to go off the rails!

## 4. Reclassifying a raster

```
# Define the changes we want to make using reclassify()
reclassification_scheme = tibble::tribble(
        ~from,  ~to, ~becomes
       , 0   , 0.1,    5
       , 0.1 , 0.2 ,   15
       , 0.2 , 0.3 ,   25
       , 0.3 , 0.4 ,   35
       , 0.4 , 0.5 ,   45
       , 0.5 , 0.6 ,   55
       , 0.6 , 0.7 ,   65
       , 0.7 , 0.8 ,   75
       , 0.8 , 0.9 ,   85
       , 0.9 , 1.0 ,   95
    )
```

```
# Attempt to apply this scheme in a block-by-block fashion
process_large_raster(
    input_raster = large_raster
  , f = function( x ) raster::reclassify( x, cfg$reclassification_scheme)
)

#             GB
# available : 3.52
#       60% : 2.11
#    needed : 0.05
#   allowed : 4.66  (if available)

# Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
#   unable to find an inherited method for function ‘reclassify’
#   for signature ‘"numeric"’
```

If you look at the source code for the `raster` package, specifically https://rdrr.io/cran/raster/src/R/reclassify.R, you see:

```
# Author: Robert J. Hijmans
# Date :  June 2008
# Version 1.0
# Licence GPL v3

setMethod('reclassify', signature(x='Raster', rcl='ANY'), 
function(x, rcl, filename='', include.lowest=FALSE, right=TRUE, ...) {
  
  filename <- trim(filename)
  ...
```

This part, `signature(x='Raster', rcl='ANY')`, says we can use reclassify on a Raster object. However, our block-by-block scheme is returning a vector, matrix, list, or something else, for which the reclassify function has no corresponding signature. When we pass one of those non-Raster objects to `reclassify`, it is not happy.

Farther down in `reclassify.R`, the function is already structured to process block-by-block, so it is a bit of a mystery why `reclassify()` did not do better out of the box:

```
   for (i in 1:tr$n) {
      vals <- getValues( x, row=tr$row[i], nrows=tr$nrows[i] )
      vals <- .reclassify(vals, rcl, include.lowest, right, leftright, onlyNA, valNA)
      if (nl > 1) {
        vals <- matrix(vals, ncol=nl)
      }
      out <- writeValues(out, vals, tr$row[i])
      pbStep(pb, i)
    }
```

And this statement, `.reclassify(vals, rcl, include.lowest, right, leftright, onlyNA, valNA)` is calling a C++ function to do the actual work.  Can we can gain any speed-up by putting the business part of reclassify() into our block-by-block function? There is only one way to find out!

## A Hack

The `.reclassify()` function is internal to the `raster` package, so we cannot call it like any other function. Instead, we must use the triple-colon (`:::`) operator. Accessing internal functions from published packages is generally *not* recommended, since unexported functions typically have no documentation and as such have no guarantee from the package authors that they will keep doing what they do now. Our hack will likely break at some point in the future when the package is improved and some of the internals change without warning. Still, it could be interesting to see what happens!

```
# A function that calls the internal function, .reclassify()
reclassify_hack <- function( x ){
  raster:::.reclassify(
      x
    , as.matrix( reclassification_scheme )
    , dolowest = FALSE
    , doright = TRUE
    , doleftright = FALSE
    , NAonly = FALSE
    , NAval = NA
  )
}
```

```
process_large_raster( input_raster = large_raster, f = reclassify_hack )

#             GB
# available : 2.92
#       60% : 1.75
#    needed : 0.05
#   allowed : 4.66  (if available)

# class      : RasterLayer 
# dimensions : 1230, 1877, 2308710  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution : 0.0002695, 0.0002695  (x, y)
# extent     : -121.9, -121.4, 37.85, 38.19  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
# source     : memory
# names      : layer 
# values     : 5, 35  (min, max)

# It worked! (on this test file, anyway)
```

## 5. Parallel computing

> I tried to use clusterR(..reclassify..) to use more cores and speed this up, but I never did seem to manage to actually speed things up, no matter how many cores I set.

As mentioned in [http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~luke/R/cluster/cluster.html](http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/%7Eluke/R/cluster/cluster.html):

- Communication is much slower than computation.
- Communication is serialized in this simple design.
- Some R functions produce large results--reduce on the compute node before returning.

Perhaps parallel computing will work better in combination with optimal chunk size.

The general idea would be to distribute the blocks among processors (and then combine the results) in such a way as to minimize network and disk bottlenecks.

For help with that, please provide an example large raster.